# Listbox within a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Could someone please point me in the right direction regarding the above?

I have a datagrid returning multiple rows via sqlite query. Within each row I need a listbox which should return multiple items associated with that row. I’m returning the reference id from the parent table in the datagrid as a column but can’t seem to find a solution to return the child records in the listbox.

I’m thinking I need to do this via a “DataGridTemplateColumn” or something.

Question 1: How would this be structured in the xaml
Question 2: How would I iterate through sql to present datagrid rows with child listbox items in code behind or any other method

Graphical Representation of what I need
[image]

**NOTE: Each ListBox needs to be editable as well**

```
public void getItems()
    {
        try
        {
            string thisPermitID = "1";

            DataTable potentialHazards;
            String query = "select JSAPH.JobSafetyAnalysisStepPotentialHazardID \"JobSafetyAnalysisStepPotentialHazardID\""
                + ", JSA.RefPermitID \"RefPermitID\""
                + ", JSAPH.RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID \"RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID\""
                + ", JSAS.StepDescription \"StepDescription\""
                + ", JSAPH.PotentialHazard \"PotentialHazard\""
                + " from JobSafetyAnalysis JSA"
                + " inner join JobSafetyAnalysisStep JSAS on JSAS.RefJobSafetyAnalysisID = JSA.JobSafetyAnalysisID"
                + " inner join JobSafetyAnalysisStepPotentialHazard JSAPH on JSAPH.RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID = JSAS.JobSafetyAnalysisStepID"
                + " where RefPermitID = '" + thisPermitID + "'";

            potentialHazards = db.GetDataTable(query);

            List<Item> PotentialHazardSelectedList = new List<Item>();

            foreach (DataRow r in potentialHazards.Rows)
            {
                if (Items != null)
                {
                    Items.Add(new Item()
                    {
                        Name = r["StepDescription"].ToString(),
                        ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { r["PotentialHazard"].ToString() }
                    });
                }

            }

            this.DataContext = Items;

        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            String error = "The following error has occurred:\n\n";
            error += fail.Message.ToString() + "\n\n";
            MessageBox.Show(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmmm, just cam across this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645014/binding-collection-listbox-datagrid?rq=1 and will see if that works for me...

Comment: ... not quite what I was looking for... reason for using listbox was to be able to edit list items via listbox to listbox method.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'll have to create them in code, and bind to them on the XAML

Comment: Could a person use a Resource styled setter to do this?

Comment: could you show us the queries, or how the data looks, or just mock up a fake screenshot of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: Just added image of what I'm after

Comment: As much as I'd love to give an answer, I believe @Sehridan's answer below nails it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not yet had any answers, I will provide you with a basic example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item Collection">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now to fill this, you'd need a collection of objects, each with a `Name` property and an `Items` collection property:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged // implement this interface properly
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SomeType> ItemCollection { get; set; }
}
```

In a view model, or code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

As for filling the `Items` collection with `Item` objects, there are several ways to achieve this. You'd basically need to join on a number of tables, either in a `SQL` query or a `LinQ` query. You could do it in one pass, or get the names first and then iterate the collection to then add the inner items to the `ItemCollection` property... whatever you feel comfortable with.

---

UPDATE >>>

You need exactly what I put in the example... a collection of data objects that *each have a collection property of some type*. Just be careful how you populate the inner collections... for testing, you could do something like this:

```
Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Bob", Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>() { 
    new SomeType() { Something = "One" }, new SomeType() { Something = "Two" }, 
    new SomeType() { Something = "Three" } } } );
Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Jane", Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>() { 
    new SomeType() { Something = "A" }, new SomeType() { Something = "B" }, 
    new SomeType() { Something = "C" } } } );
```

Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
foreach (string value in values)
{
    Item item = new Item() { Name = value };
    foreach (SomeType someType in SomeTypes.Where(s => s.Something == value))
    {
        item.ItemCollection.Add(someType);
    }
    Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan... thanks for your input above... I've implemented as above and am stuck on the last bit. I've created a view to combine my tables etc. What would the structure be regarding the iterating over the sql results? (Would like to do it in one pass)

Comment: That all depends on the structure of your data. There is an example of what this looks like using `LinQ2SQL` in my answer to the [Data Entities > Domain Objects > ViewModels, each with drastically different data structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693682/data-entities-domain-objects-viewmodels-each-with-drastically-different-dat/19694623#comment29312293_19694623) post.

Comment: Hi Sheridan... I think I'm making a hash of things... this is what I've done.. please help if you can... will post code above in question

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you want me to help with. Please explain further.

Comment: I've sort of used some of your suggestions from above (Name and ItemCollection) and amalgamated into my code as in

Comment: Name  is StepDescription
and my ItemCollection should be PotentialHazard

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure if the code is correct (looks a mess) and I'm not getting the ItemCollection working. Also no UI output...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any of that, so I have no idea what you've done. Did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly on all of the properties? Also, have you set the `UserControl.DataContext` to an instance of your view model/code behind?

Comment: You can find further help with the `DataGrid` Class from the [`DataGrid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Ok managed to get data to present in GridView.. problem is that each row is duplicated for every record... I.E I guess I need a many to one for listbox only per row... If that makes sense...

Comment: Hi all... I managed to get the listbox to present correct data. I now need to be able to update each row in datagrid (done) and each row listbox item to database and am unable to get items from my listbox. Any help would be appreciated